# Client-Server handling errors

Tags: java, sockets, client, server

I want to build a Client-Server application using Socket from Java language. The Client communicates with the Server using different sequences of bytes. My question is what’s the best way to handling the correct format of the messages, to the Server side or both, Client and Server?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One initial thought: shared code! If the code that is used to generate your byte sequences is the SAME on client and server (versus having two different implementations to do the same thing).

Comment: The user has to introduce different requests formats (example: START 40), each one with a specific 4 bytes header, to the Server, but in case of typing an inexistent command I don’t know if it’s better to control the message on the Client side or send it to the Server and wait for an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You will **ALWAYS** have to check the correctness and sanity of messages arriving at the server. **ALWAYS**. Because people can **ALWAYS** reverse-engineer the protocol and develop their own clients. So whatever sanity checks you have in your client, they could be bypassed.

You might want to do the sanity checks in a library, as far as applicable, and use that library not only in the server but also in the client. Depending on your application, it might make sense to prevent insane messages from being generated in the client in the first place. But as I said, that's no replacement for the server-side checks.

Comment: Yes, that is my question. In the Server side always need to check the errors. If this happens, it makes sense to make the same check on the Client? In case of error, the connection will end. The advantage is that the Client could control this and avoid sending to server the erroneous message.

Comment: As I already explained in the answer, it can make sense, but that really depends on your use case.